# numpy overlap ratio of rectangles

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have an array containing arrays of coordinates like this:

```
a = [[0,0,300,400],[1,1,15,59],[5,5,300,400]]
```

Now I want to get the overlap ratio of each rectangle to the other rectangles:

```
def bool_rect_intersect(A, B):
    return not (B[0]>A[2] or B[2]<A[0] or B[3]<A[1] or B[1]>A[3])


def get_overlap_ratio(A, B):
    in_ = bool_rect_intersect(A, B)
    if not in_:
        return 0
    else:
        left = max(A[0], B[0]);
        top = max(A[1], B[1]);
        right = min(A[2], B[2]);
        bottom = min(A[3], B[3]);
        intersection = [left, top, right, bottom];
        surface_intersection = (intersection[2]-intersection[0])*(intersection[3]-intersection[1]);
        surface_A = (A[2]- A[0])*(A[3]-A[1]) + 0.0;
        return surface_intersection / surface_A
```

Now i'm looking for the fastest way to compute the grid of overlaps for arrays of size 2000+.
If I loop over it it takes more than a minute. I tried np.vectorize, but i don't think this is applicable in a multidimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's a vectorized approach -

```
def pairwise_overlaps(a):
    r,c = np.triu_indices(a.shape[0],1)

    lt = np.maximum(a[r,:2], a[c,:2])
    tb = np.minimum(a[r,2:], a[c,2:])

    si_vectorized = (tb[:,0] - lt[:,0]) * (tb[:,1] - lt[:,1])
    slicedA_comps = ((a[:,2]- a[:,0])*(a[:,3]-a[:,1]) + 0.0)
    sA_vectorized = np.take(slicedA_comps, r)
    return si_vectorized/sA_vectorized
```

Sample run -

```
In [48]: a
Out[48]: 
array([[  0,   0, 300, 400],
       [  1,   1,  15,  59],
       [  5,   5, 300, 400]])

In [49]: print get_overlap_ratio(a[0], a[1]) # Looping thru pairs
    ...: print get_overlap_ratio(a[0], a[2])
    ...: print get_overlap_ratio(a[1], a[2])
    ...: 
0.00676666666667
0.971041666667
0.665024630542

In [50]: pairwise_overlaps(a) # Proposed app to get all those in one-go
Out[50]: array([ 0.00676667,  0.97104167,  0.66502463])
```

---

**Approach #2 :** Upon close inspection, we will see that in the previous approach, the indexing with the `r`'s and `c`'s would be performance killers as they will make copies. We can improve on this, by performing computations for each element in a column against each of other elements in the same column, as listed in the implementation below -

```
def pairwise_overlaps_v2(a):
    rl = np.minimum(a[:,2], a[:,None,2]) - np.maximum(a[:,0], a[:,None,0])
    bt = np.minimum(a[:,3], a[:,None,3]) - np.maximum(a[:,1], a[:,None,1])
    si_vectorized2D = rl*bt
    slicedA_comps = ((a[:,2]- a[:,0])*(a[:,3]-a[:,1]) + 0.0)  
    overlaps2D = si_vectorized2D/slicedA_comps[:,None]

    r = np.arange(a.shape[0])
    tril_mask = r[:,None] < r
    return overlaps2D[tril_mask]
```

### Runtime test

```
In [238]: n = 1000

In [239]: a = np.hstack((np.random.randint(0,100,(n,2)), \  
                         np.random.randint(300,500,(n,2))))

In [240]: np.allclose(pairwise_overlaps(a), pairwise_overlaps_v2(a))
Out[240]: True

In [241]: %timeit pairwise_overlaps(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.2 ms per loop

In [242]: %timeit pairwise_overlaps_v2(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop
```

Let's add in the original approach as loop-comprehension -

```
In [244]: r,c = np.triu_indices(a.shape[0],1)

In [245]: %timeit [get_overlap_ratio(a[r[i]], a[c[i]]) for i in range(len(r))]
1 loops, best of 3: 2.85 s per loop
```

Around **`180x`** speedup there with the second approach over the original one!